# Method bounded by a const generic expression does not satisfy trait bound

Tags: matrix, rust, raytracing, const-generics

I'm currently implementing a ray tracer following along the book "The Ray Tracer Challenge" by Jamis Buck.

I've arrived at the part where I have to implement a few methods on matrices, and since these matrices have a compile time known size, I chose to implement them using `const generics expressions` (which are still only available on the nightly channel).

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
```

The `Matrix` type is defined as the following:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Matrix<const N: usize>(pub [[f64; N]; N]);
```

I implemented the following methods:

```rust
impl<const N: usize> Matrix<N> {
    fn submatrix(&self, index: Idx) -> Matrix<{ N - 1 }> {
        //...
    }

    fn minor(&self, index: Idx) -> f64
    where
        [(); N - 1]:,
    {
        let submatrix = self.submatrix(index);
        submatrix.determinant()
    }

    fn cofactor(&self, index: Idx) -> f64
    where
        [(); N - 1]:,
    {
        let minor = self.minor(index);
        //...
    }

    fn determinant(&self) -> f64
    where
        [(); N - 1]:,
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

... but I'm running into an issue with the `submatrix` method, which returns a `Matrix<{ N - 1 }>`.

When calling the `determinant` method on a `submatrix`, which is what we do in the `minor` method:

```rust
fn minor(&self, index: Idx) -> f64
    where
        [(); N - 1]:,
    {
        let submatrix: Matrix<{ N - 1 }> = self.submatrix(index);
        submatrix.determinant()
    }
```

... even though the `minor` method is bounded by the following constraint:

```rust
where [(); N - 1]:,
```

... the compiler still complains and suggests to add the same `where bound using this expression`:

```rust
error: unconstrained generic constant
   --> src/rt/matrix.rs:109:19
    |
109 |         submatrix.determinant()
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: try adding a `where` bound using this expression: `where [(); N - 1]:`
note: required by a bound in `Matrix::<N>::determinant`
   --> src/rt/matrix.rs:128:14
    |
126 |     fn determinant(&self) -> f64
    |        ----------- required by a bound in this
127 |     where
128 |         [(); N - 1]:,
    |              ^^^^^ required by this bound in `Matrix::<N>::determinant`
```

I tried to implement the `minor` method for `Matrix<{ N - 1 }>` but it does not seem to work either (or rather I have no idea how to do that, or if that's even possible):

```rust
impl<const N: usize> Matrix<{ N - 1 }> {
    fn minor(&self, index: Idx) -> f64 {
        let submatrix = self.submatrix(index);
        submatrix.determinant()
    }
```

... which gives the following error:

```rust
error[E0207]: the const parameter `N` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
   --> src/rt/matrix.rs:138:12
    |
138 | impl<const N: usize> Matrix<{ N - 1 }> {
    |            ^ unconstrained const parameter
    |
    = note: expressions using a const parameter must map each value to a distinct output value
    = note: proving the result of expressions other than the parameter are unique is not supported
```

I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do here with the `submatrix` is even possible. It's not a big deal since I can define these methods for each possible N, which in my case are limited to `2_usize`, `3_usize` and `4_usize`, but implementing these methods only for `Matrix<N>` would be a lot cleaner!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning:** The `generic_const_exprs` feature is *extremely* unstable! Do not use it in production!

---

You call `determinant()` on `submatrix`, which is already `Matrix<{ N - 1 }>` (returned from `submatrix()`). So you can to also restrict it to `where [(); N - 1 - 1]:,` (note that the Rust compiler is not smart enough to understand this is the same as `where [(); N - 2]:,`, nor it is able to conclude that if this holds then also `where [(); N - 1]:,`. You have to write both: `where [(); N - 1]:, [(); N - 1 - 1]:,`):

```
    fn minor(&self, index: Idx) -> f64
    where
        [(); N - 1]:,
        [(); N - 1 - 1]:,
    {
        let submatrix = self.submatrix(index);
        submatrix.determinant()
    }

    fn cofactor(&self, index: Idx) -> f64
    where
        [(); N - 1]:,
        [(); N - 1 - 1]:,
    {
        let minor = self.minor(index);
        //...
    }
```